# Why QML variables cannot be uppercase?

Tags: qml

`property string CarColor: "red"`
Compilation output:
error: Property names cannot begin with an upper case letter.

Comment: It is a rule that allows QML to interpret if it is a type or a variable.

Answer (score 0):

QML property rules coincide with many of JavaScript's property rules, for example, property names must begin with a lowercase letter. [JavaScript reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) are not valid property names.

This is a rule you should get used to the same way that you've already used to the rules that properties...

- can't start begin with number
- can't contain spaces
- can't contain special characters like `@#%^&*`...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, Javascript DOES allow uppercase property names. And even if it didn't, your answer still doesn't answer WHY variables can't be uppercase. I personally imagine that the answer is "an arbitrary decision by someone 30 years ago that just never got changed"